# FULL Debian installation on USB

Tags: linux, debian, installation, usb-flash-drive

I tried to make a full Debian installation on USB.

I created a live Debian on USB1 with Rufus. no problem. I opened the live session, inserted USB2 and followed all installation steps (graphical) incl. putting GRUB all on that USB2.

At the end I received a confirmation that the installation was complete but when I try to boot from that USB2 (full Debian) I only get the black screen with blinking cursor.

Where did I go wrong?

FYI: installation without an internet connection. Could that matter?

Comment: It depends on the host's hardware. Sometimes you do need an Internet connection to load additional drivers.

Comment: So first you successfully booted a live Debian USB, then did you try doing a full / regular install onto the same USB?

Comment: I updated the question: there are of course two usb pieces: 1 with live Debian, 2 where I intend to make full/complete installation.

Comment: I would like to mimic this Ubuntu recipe but for Debian [link](https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/432396-installing-full-ubuntu-onto-usb-flash-drive/)

Comment: I am using a  _complete installation image_.

Answer (score 2):

The boot flag on USB2 may not be set.  The Debian installer lets you set this flag but I think it does not do this by default on existing partitions.

Boot off your live CD, open a root terminal, and run `cfdisk /dev/sdX` where `/dev/sdX` is your USB2 (use `blkid` or `lsblk` if you don't know for sure).  Make the partition where `/boot` lives bootable.  Write the changes and see if you can boot off of it now.

Comment: It is write protected

Comment: If your USB2 is write protected you need to fix that.  If the drive suddenly became write protected out of nowhere, it could be due to the flash drive going bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a debian live USB with persistence from a debian based operating system using [`mkusb`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/install-to-debian) tools (tested and work fine on debian jessie KDE)

If you don't have debian installed you can use 2 USB :

The first one is your current debian Live  USB

The second USB is used to create the debian persistent live USB

Boot from your live USB then plug in your second USB

Open the terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add the following line:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mkusb/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
```

Save your file ( Ctrl + O ) then press Enter

Run the foolowing command:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 54B8C8AC
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mkusb
```

Run the program .

Choose:

1. "Install (make a boot device)"
2. p : persistent live
3. upefi : usb-pack-efi
4. choose your Usb device ( becarful if you are using 2 USB , run `fdisk -l` before pluging the second one)
5. check Go

You will be asked to set the percentage of the persistent partition ( e,g: 50%) then validate , it will take about 15 min .

Comment: my intention is to make a full installation on usb2 (a live Debian I already have on usb1 and it works)

Comment: @SuzukiBlue Ok i will edit my answer , What is your current Linux system ( debian , ubuntu ....) ?

Comment: great, thanks. I am new to linux reason why for the moment I would like to have it on a pen drive for testing (but full version). os installed on my machine is windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem (black screen with blinking cursor after install and reboot). The solution for me was to create a new bootable USB stick with YUMI. That worked. My explanation is that something must have been wrong with the first one, I'm not sure exactly what. What changed is:

1. different USB stick (different brand and larger capacity)
2. different program to create it (YUMI in my case, but you could try UNetbootin, too)
3. it is possible I downloaded a new iso, although I cannot say for sure.

Comment: thanks a lot, I tried UNetbootin. everything took much longer but the end result the same: black screen with blinking cursor... :(

Comment: @SuzukiBlue Another thing you could try is switch to UEFI mode (or legacy, depending on which one you tried already).

Answer (score 0):

This could be a number of problems, but one thing that should always be done before installation of a distribution is verifying the checksum of the ISO file you downloaded to make sure it is fully intact. You can find the Debian specific info on this [here](https://www.debian.org/CD/verify).

Oh and to answer your other question, if this Debian image you are using is indeed the 'full' version, no, you do not need an internet connection because as 'full' implies, everything needed is included in the ISO image.